# How to allow some of the APIs to be accessed by registered clients?

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I have two types of APIs. Some of them can be accessed if the client is registered with us. He need not ask a user for auhorization_grant code first and then get an access_token to access those APIs. The rest of the APIs are secured by normal oauth flow. Is there any SpEL expression which would help me here ?
What details would a client need to pass in the request for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the client is accessing the APIs on it's own behalf, and not on behalf of a user, then the client credentials grant sounds like it would be suitable.

Then, you can use the oauth2 method level security expression "!#oauth2.isClient()" in the PreAuthorize annotation to prevent clients accessing the resource as themselves

```
@PreAuthorize("!#oauth2.isClient()")
```

Comment: But once the client has an access_token using client_credentials grant_type, she will be able to access any API with that access_token, right ?

Comment: If you have the oauth2 method level security expressions configured, you could use "!#oauth2.isClient" to prevent clients accessing the resource as themselves.

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you so much. 
`!#oauth2.isClient()` is the correct thing by the way.

`@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('listing') and !#oauth2.isClient()")` is what I used exactly.
Can you please edit your answer ? I'll mark this as correct answer then. :)